# How to copy or post an entire table in html code to another page?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I'm trying to make an Invoice Table, later when the customer finishes, I want them to see the same product they ordered in another page!

I tried using HTML post method, but that doesn't work, because I'm using a JScript function to add rows and delete.

So to be clear, I want to know if it is possible to clone, or copy the entire table to another page with the content or without the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add and remove rows in your table,
you could also add and remove **hidden form values** for a form.

That form would have a submit button which sends you to the target page.

That target page takes the form values and produces a nice table again.

---

Either you take the form values with you with those hidden values
or you could store them temporarily in the session...

Answer (score 0):

When users add and remove rows, the data is sent to the server, right? So just display the invoice on the other page. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: The user adds the rows, so for example each row is a product, and I want when the user finishes to next ->going to another page which would show a report of what he/she ordered! This Page will be 1 step after adding the products, and 1 step before confirming the whole thing to the database, so in case the customer missed something they could go back and add it!

Comment: I think you should save every modification to the database. You can mark the order as uncomplete until they confirm the 3rd step and allow them to go back to edit their order.

Comment: Robin thanks for your advice, I mean that is a good way, but I want to use another way, and the thing is they required it from me to not add this to the db.. I mean I can get it as a temp value as well, but I just wanted to know if there is any other way available! Thanks